# Uninstalled graphics card driver in attempt to fix issue with csgo

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card

when I launched CSGO, I could hear the intro music and when the main menu loaded i could hear the hover button sounds it makes when you move your mouse over the buttons, but the problem is, the screen was black the whole time. I alt tabbed out and my system was perfectly usable but i tabbed back in and it was still like that.

I have intel HD Graphics as well as an ATI mobility radeon 5000 in the laptop, but i thought that rolling back intel hd graphics would be the right choice, and I did it and now CSGO won't even start up, quoting an "Engine error".

[image]

Someone on reddit said to use the amd catalyst control center to make csgo use the amd gpu, but i accidentally uninstalled it thinking it was causing the problem. I reinstalled it and all the presets were gone. Any way about solving this issue?

(Here is what catalyst control center looks like on my pc.)
[image]

Also in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1226035/will-wiping-a-computer-reinstall-my-video-card-drivers/1226037#1226037) I ask about just wiping my computer so that it will fix itself, which is a possible solution right now because the computer is new and I am not losing anything

Comment: Update the chipset and the Radeon drivers to latest version.

Comment: @Overmind I used the chipset installer from intel, it said Unknown Error. I succesfully updated radeon drivers. Is there a way I can get csgo to stop using the intel one and switch over to the amd one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Catalyst Control Center.

Click “Power” and select “Switchable Graphics.”

Choose an application from the list or browse and select an application and assign the appropriate GPU. Select CSGO there and assign it the Radeon.

Note that you need both drivers installed. If the chipset one does not work, find a version that does.

Comment: I reinstalled the control center and now theres no profile or whatever. http://prntscr.com/frn7it

Comment: Use 'add presets' to create one.

Comment: Ok so I need to remake the power preset. There are a bunch of fields, what should I put for each field? the name field is Power i suppose, but what about the rest?

Comment: @Overmind - Intel has not published Windows 10 drivers for the Intel iGPU, so it's difficult to install drivers, that do not exist for his OS.