# Will wiping a computer reinstall my video card drivers?

Tags: windows-10

(this is a laptop)
I completely screwed over my computer by rolling back my intel hd graphics card drivers by accident. if i use windows' reset options to completely wipe my computer, will it reinstall drivers properly during the reinstallation?

[image]

In this picture these are the two display adapters that I have.

Originally, the bottom one used to say "Intel HD Graphics", but i went into its properties and clicked Roll back. Upon restarting it changed to "Microsoft Basic Display Adapter" as seen above.

**NOTE: The intel driver is already gone since i rolled it back to Microsoft Basic Display Adapter. I'm trying to get it back.**

The intel website says you need to identify your graphics controller first. Before i rolled it back, mine was intel hd graphics, but now I removed it and so it wouldn't even work. I have an i7-640m cpu. I could only find graphics media acclerators for legacy cpus, and when i installed it an error popped up saying i did not meet requirements. the legacy CPU page did not list anything compatible with windows 10. I just want to get my old driver back, called Intel HD Graphics without a version number at the end.

edit: I ran windows update and it says my computer is up to date.

I cannot run games with the basic adapter.

I tried updating stuff and uninstalled some updates then reinstalled them and restarted the computer a bunch of times and sometimes the updates took too long so i held down the power button. The computer is now agonizingly slow, with no more smooth movements. Everything is laggy.

Edit: Everything is fixed. I didn't look closely enough and all I had to do was go to the HP page for my *specific* laptop.

Comment: Anyways, you should update your question, with the relevant information.

Comment: Windows 10 drivers do not exists for your iGPU.  You should be using your AMD dGPU to run games (it's much better).

Comment: @Ramhound will do. this brings me back to the OP: if i were to wipe and reinstall windows would that somehow bring it back?

Comment: If you Reset your installation your drivers will NOT be reinstalled.

Comment: I should be using my AMD gpu but to switch it i need to use the AMD catalyst control center. it had profiles but i reinstalled catalyst control center by accident. i need to recreate the profiles. https://superuser.com/posts/comments/1793519?noredirect=1 I'm not sure what to put in each field.

Comment: What about the manufacturers website?  That's where you should be getting the proper drivers.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths hp tells me to use windows update, so i'll try that.

Comment: @Ramhound if reinstalling wont, will system restore bring the driver back somehow?

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths i couldn't find the drivers using windows update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically download drivers separately, but in this case, I'd use [DDU](http://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html), or Display Driver Uninstaller, then re-install the drivers from AMD

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
Win + X. Click Run and type: msinfo32, and then hit enter. Select Components, then Display. May you see the Intel HD GPU you are using?

You have then two options:

1. You can then download the Intel HD driver from your OEM: Asus, Lenovo etc.
2. You can install and run the Intel Driver Utility to scan the driver:
   https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24345/Intel-Driver-Update-Utility

Comment: [this is the Microsoft Basic Display Adapter](http://prntscr.com/fs697m), and this is the [AMD Mobility Radeon HD 5000 series](http://prntscr.com/fs69v9).